# How to unittest symfony2 core

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

After a fresh symfony2 install i can run `phpunit -c app/` and phpunit tests the included demo application: `OK (1 test, 1 assertion)`.

But i receive no output (even with verbosity) when i run `phpunit -c vendor/symfony/` as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/contributing/code/tests.html.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

- PHPUnit: 3.6.2
- PHP: 5.3.8
- Symfony: 2.0.5

Testing twig, doctrine and other plugins works as expected (although doctrine tests fail for some reason).

Comment: Did you check the symfony source code? For symfony 1.x they include a whole library of tests in /test dir.

Comment: I got 2 directories in vendor/symfony/tests/Symfony/Tests: Bridge and Component. Both contain plenty of test cases ("extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase").

Comment: Running phpunit against /app may not work because you have to setup your own unit tests. There is no way for symfony to know how you are going to build your apps. But it should at least run the unit tests against the core code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no output it's maybe because you configured php not to display errors.

You must install the vendors using the `vendors.php` script before lauching the Symfony test suite:

```
$ php vendor/symfony/vendors.php
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought i already installed them by executing `php bin/vendors install`

Comment: Well this is the correct answer. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to vote it up (not enough rep). What dazzles me though is the fact that the symfony2 tests abort at approx 66% without any notice. :/ I'm going to head over to the symfony forums and ask what's up with that.

Comment: I think the output is empty because of your PHP configuration (error reporting, show errors, ...). As Symfony comes with a huge test suite, you should try to increase the maximum allowed memory in your php.ini.

Comment: The error was indeed a wrong error_reporting setting n php.ini. Had a typo there. :/ It works with `E_ALL | E_STRICT`. 24 tests still fail... something about time and currency formats. Anyway, main problem solved. Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the tests using the provided `phpunit.xml.dist` configuration file?

From your projects root directory:

```
$ phpunit --configuration app/phpunit.xml.dist vendor/symfony/tests
```

That should add an autoloader for vendors.

Comment: Yep, thats what why I used the "-c" option (identical to "--configuration").